# React/Redux Changing Webpage language

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm making a website that have a functionality to change languages from the homescreen, I'm using Redux to handle the state.

I keep getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined, and It seems to be from Home.js, I dont know why it happens!!, Please Help !!!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactRedux from 'react-redux';

import './Home.css';
import Navbar from '../../Reusable/Navbar/Navbar.js';
import Footer from '../../Reusable/Footer/Footer.js';
import Action from '../../Reusable/Action/Action.js';
import ProjectsCarousel from '../../Reusable/ProjectsCarousel/ProjectsCarousel.js';
import Getintouch from '../../Reusable/Getintouch/Getintouch.js';
import Header from './Header/Header.js';
import Info from './Info/Info.js';
import Whyus from './Whyus/Whyus.js';
import Testimonial from './Testimonial/Testimonial.js';
let actions = require('../../../actions');

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
        const content = this.props.content;
        const switchLanguage = this.props.switchLanguage;

        if (content){
              return (
                <div className="home">
                  <Action />
                  <Navbar data={content.page.menu} switchLanguage={switchLanguage}/>
                  <Header />
                  <Info  data={content.page.home}/>
                  <ProjectsCarousel />
                  <Whyus />
                  <Testimonial />
                  <Getintouch />
                  <Footer />
                </div>
              )
        } else {
          return;
        }

  }
}


module.exports = ReactRedux.connect(
  (state) => ({content: state.content}),
  (dispatch) => ({switchLanguage: (lang) => dispatch(actions.switchLanguage(lang))})
)(Home);

export default Home;
```

Comment: Based on your code, the only thing I can image is that `ReactRedux` (line 2) is itself undefined. What does `console.log(ReactRedux)` output to the dev console?

Comment: It gives me the same error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because [react-redux has only named exports](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/index.js).

change your import to:

```
import * as ReactRedux from 'react-redux';
```

which will import every named property to `ReactRedux` Object. or import it like:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export default connect(
  (state) => ({content: state.content}),
  (dispatch) => ({switchLanguage: (lang) => dispatch(actions.switchLanguage(lang))})
)(Home);
```

Comment: I used import * as ReactRedux from 'react-redux'; and it gives me

TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'


  40 | }
  41 | 
  42 | 
> 43 | module.exports = ReactRedux.connect(
  44 |   (state) => ({content: state.content}),
  45 |   (dispatch) => ({switchLanguage: (lang) => dispatch(actions.switchLanguage(lang))})
  46 | )(Home);

Comment: I used import * as ReactRedux from 'react-redux'; and it gives me

TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'


> 43 | module.exports = ReactRedux.connect(

Comment: @walidElnozahy what about: `import { connect } from 'react-redux';` ?

Comment: Failed to compile. 'ReactRedux' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: @walidElnozahy see the edit. You need to use `connect` directly

Comment: I used your direct connect and I keep getting 
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'

Comment: @walidElnozahy I see. I think `module.exports` is unnecessary here. Try using just `export default` as in the edit I made.

Comment: can you please take a look here there is some problem with the routing, would really appreciate your help : 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49601366/using-react-router-with-redux